# Realizar carga de datos que comiencen con 0 en oracle y mantener

Tags: php, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy realizando este query en una DB de oracle

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO  VT_PEDIDOS_CABECERA (COD_EMPRESA, TIP_COMPROBANTE, SER_COMPROBANTE, NRO_COMPROBANTE,COD_SUCURSAL, FEC_COMPROBANTE,  COD_CLIENTE, COD_VENDEDOR, COD_CONDICION_VENTA, COD_LISTA_PRECIO, COD_MONEDA, TIP_CAMBIO, TOT_COMPROBANTE, ESTADO, COD_USUARIO, TEL_CLIENTE, RUC, PROCESADO, NOM_CLIENTE, DIR_CLIENTE, COD_SUCURSAL_STK, IND_COBRADO, TIPO_COBRO, NUM_AUTORIZACION, NOMB_CIUDAD, DIR_MAIL) VALUES (1, 'PED', '002-002', :nro_comprobante , 74, :fec_comprobante, 0, '00', 9, '01', 1, 1, :tot_comprobante, 'P', 'ECOMMERCE', :tel_cliente, :ruc, 'P', :nom_cliente, :dir_cliente, 12, 'S', :tipo_cobro, 0, :nomb_ciudad,:dir_mail)");
```

Y lo que necesito es mantener el valor de 00 y el de 01 que se carguen así como el 0 por delante, el dato que admite esa columna es Varchar2(5), ya probe usando comillas y sin comillas y en todas me la carga como 0 y 1

Comment: Puedes agregar la estructura de la tabla? Si es de tipo `Varchar` debería funcionar.

Comment: COD_VENDEDOR VARCHAR2(5), Esa es la columna en cuestion, ya trate desde agregar solo, usando comillas, desde una variable, hasta llamandola desde el oci_bind_by_name

Comment: podrías intentar alterar tu campo y cambiarlo por  ***INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL***. el zerofill te permite agregar ceros a la izquierda, ***nunca lo e intentado con un campo tipo varchar pero podrías intentar agregar solo esta linea UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL despues de tu varchar2(5)***